# List multi-stage automated test run results, on a per-stage basis, using Azure DevOps GET Api?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, multistage-pipeline

Is there a way to list multi-stage automated test run results, on a per stage basis, using Azure DevOps GET Api?

If you call `/_apis/pipelines/{pl_def_id}/runs` , you will get a list of builds from a defined pipeline.

If you get the latest build from that list, and if that build is `multi-stage`, the `test runs` do not seem to be hierarchically beneath the latest build, as you might expect.

To get the test runs, when you call `/_apis/test/runs`, ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/runs/list ) it only can give you the list of ALL runs within your org+project.   There does not seem to be an id that references the multi-staged "test runs" tasks back to the "parent pipeline" having a "build id".

I looked at `timeline` queries, but they don't seem to have that info either.

HOW can this be achieved with ADO GET api? Am I overlooking the answer?

Answer (score 0):

There is a parameter  `buildUri` in the run list API  as you mentioned the doc:[Run List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/runs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP)

You can use `buildUri` to get test runs from  a specified build of pipeline.

However, if you want to get multi-stage automated test run results on a per stage, I’m afraid that there’s no supported API to achieve it.
You may submit a feature request at website below:

[feature request](https://%20https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest?space=21)

Comment: Does it work for you ? If it helps, you could also accept the answer, this will help other users who has the same issue.